# How to implement static members (non-function) on javascript CLASSES (ES6)

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I have a class that only holds a static method, and there is no need to ever instantiate it. I want this class to wrap an "enum" with static values, to be used by the static method under this class. Here is a simplified example of this use case as i "wanted" it too look like:

```
class UserActionsService {

    static actionTypes = {
        foo: 1,
        bar: 2,
        buzz: 3
    };

    static doSomethingWith(actionType) {
        console.log(actoinType);
    }
}
```

and the usage should have look like:

```
UserActionsService.doSomethingWith(UserActionsService.actionTypes.buzz);
```

But, since i couldn't make the static `actionTypes` member work, i wrapped it with a static function like so:

```
class UserActionsService {

    static actionTypes() {
        return {
            foo: 1,
            bar: 2,
            buzz: 3
        };
    }

    static doSomethingWith(actionType) {
        console.log(actoinType);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
UserActionsService.doSomethingWith(UserActionsService.actionTypes().buzz);
///////////////////////////////////////////////// Ugly part here ^^
```

It works, but ugly. Am i missing something? Is there a specific reason that makes only static **methods** available, and not static members?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **getter** to get around the "ugly" syntax

```js
class UserActionsService {

    static get actionTypes() {
      return {
        foo: 1,
        bar: 2,
        buzz: 3
       };
    }

    static doSomethingWith(actionType) {
        console.log(actionType);
    }
}

UserActionsService.doSomethingWith(UserActionsService.actionTypes.buzz);
```

Comment: "*Your code should work as is*" Of course it's not. It's syntaticaly invalid, as properties are not supported.

Comment: You are correct, I incorrectly assumed he was using a transpiler such as Babel, which would let you do that. Edited the answer, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using modules, you can just make your 'enum' a plain object, on the same level as your static function, and export both as properties of a module:

### UserActionsService.js

```
const actionTypes = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  buzz: 3
}

function doSomethingWith(actionType){
   do the thing...
}

module.exports = {actionTypes, doSomethingWith};
```

### Consuming module

```
const UserActionsService = require('./UserActionsService');
UserActionsService.doSomethingWith(UserActionsService.actionTypes.buzz);
```

The ES6 'class' is really syntactic sugar in this context, and doesn't provide anything that this simple structure doesn't give you.

As far as why you can't do what you originally tried to do, it isn't (as commented by dsfq) supported syntax.

Comment: I updated the title of the question, i'm using classes, not modules... but thanks anyway!